# How to add condition to RETURN in a SQL FUNCTION?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a function in SQL server. The function returns the total sale for a given year and month. **If the return data is NULL, then return 0.**

However, I wasn't able to perform the NULL then zero condition in my function. Can I simply write like this `RETURN ISNULL(@totalsale,'0');`?

Please help me check the code. Thanks!

```
CREATE FUNCTION uf_GetSales
(@yearp int, @monthp int)
RETURNS int
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @totalsale int;
        SELECT @totalsale = sum(TotalDue) FROM SalesOrderHeader
        WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = @yearp AND MONTH(OrderDate) = @monthp
        GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)
        RETURN ISNULL(@totalsale,'0');
    END
```

Comment: You're missing a `;` after your `SELECT`, and you need to use `COALESCE`, not `ISNULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you *could* write this:

```
    RETURN ISNULL(@totalsale,'0');
```

I would recommend:

```
    RETURN COALESCE(@totalsale, 0);
```

That is, keep the types consistent.  I prefer `COALESCE()` over `ISNULL()` because it is standard.